# Can I run a coroutine in python independently from all other code?

Tags: python-3.x, coroutine

I have a piece of code that I need to be ran every hour. What's the best way to run that piece of code **independently** from all the other code (It's a telegram bot) without having to refactor everything?(Now I know I can use aiogram for this but I'm using different lib) I'm looking for something like a *unity c# coroutine* (where you simply StartCoroutine and you have that function ran in parallel), but on **python 3.9**. I've been searching so much for something not very complicated, that I'll be glad even if this piece of code interrupts my main code while executing, as it takes around 1 second to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put your code in a function, then call it using the `threading` module.

```py
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

# Here is a function that uses the sleep() function. If you called this directly, it would stop the main Python execution
def my_independent_function():
    print("Starting to sleep...")
    sleep(10)
    print("Finished sleeping.")

# Make a new thread which will run this function
t = Thread(target=my_independent_function)
# Start it in parallel
t.start()

# You can see that we can still execute other code, while other function is running
for i in range(5):
    print(i)
    sleep(1)
```

And the output:

```
Starting to sleep...
0
1
2
3
4

Finished sleeping.
```

As you can see, even while the function was sleeping, the main code execution continued.